# Jquery datatable aparece com o resultado das pesquisas anteriores ao filtrar

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, ajax, jquery-datatables

Eu possuo uma página de pesquisa feita em ASP.NET MVC que possui os dados carregados em uma tabela usando AJAX e jQuery Template, para não precisar recarregar a pagina após a pesquisa. Segue o exemplo abaixo:

```
function CarregaTabela() {

       idFiltro = $("#idFiltro").val();
       pesquisa = $("#campoPesquisa").val();

        var url = "http://servidorTeste/api/precos/";

        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                "idLoja": $("#idLoja").val(),
                "idFiltro": idFiltro,
                "Pesquisa": pesquisa,
                "TotalProdutos": $("#TotalProdutos").val()
            },
            success: function (retorno) {

                if (retorno.mensagemErro == null) {
                    //Aqui vai pra tabela de genéricos
                     if (retorno.listaPrecos.length > 0) {



                            $.notify(retorno.listaPrecos.length + " Produtos encontrados.");
                            //Oculto a tabela de genéricos.
                            $("#tabelaProdutos").hide();
                            //Removo todos os tr filhos do tbody
                            $("#corpoProdutos tr").remove();
                            //Oculto a tabela de genéricos.
                            $("#tabelaEquivalentes").hide();
                            //Removo todos os tr filhos do tbody
                            $("#corpoEquivalentes tr").remove();


                            //Foreach
                            $.each(retorno.listaPrecos, function (i, item) {
                                //Formando o preço no formato 00.00
                                item.descontoPercentagemStandard = CalcularPercentagem(item.Referencia, item.Standard).toFixed(2);
                                item.descontoPercentagemPreferencial = CalcularPercentagem(item.Referencia, item.Preferencial).toFixed(2);
                                item.descontoPercentagemAposentado = CalcularPercentagem(item.Referencia, item.Aposentado).toFixed(2);
                                item.descontoPercentagemMedico = CalcularPercentagem(item.Referencia, item.Medico).toFixed(2);
                                item.PercentagemPMC *= 100;
                                item.PercentagemPMC = item.PercentagemPMC.toFixed(2);

                                item.Referencia = item.Referencia.toFixed(2);
                                item.Standard = item.Standard.toFixed(2);
                                item.Preferencial = item.Preferencial.toFixed(2);
                                item.Aposentado = item.Aposentado.toFixed(2);
                                item.Medico = item.Medico.toFixed(2);



                                if (item.Condicao == "VENDA") {
                                    item.Valor = item.Standard - item.VmsPDV;
                                    item.Valor = item.Valor.toFixed(2);
                                }
                            });

                            //Adiciono todos os items a tabela de produtos.
                            $("#tmplProdutos").tmpl(retorno.listaPrecos).appendTo("#corpoProdutos");

                            $("#tabelaProdutos").show();

                        else {
                            $.notify(retorno.listaPrecos.length + " Produtos encontrados.");
                            //Oculto a tabela de genéricos.
                            $("#tabelaProdutos").hide();
                            //Removo todos os tr filhos do tbody
                            $("#corpoProdutos tr").remove();
                        }
                    }

                }
                else {
                    $("#tabelaProdutos").hide();
                    $.notify(retorno.mensagemErro, { status: "danger" });
                }
            },
            error: function () {
                bootbox.alert("Falha ao pesquisar produtos.");
            },
            complete: function () {
                loading.stop();
            }
        });

};
```

Recententemente implementei o jQuery Datatable nesta página de pesquisa. A primeira pesquisa ela funciona bem, mas da segunda em diante, além de exibir toda a pesquisa (sendo que deveria aparecer apenas 10 itens de cada vez), quando eu vou filtrar na barra de pesquisa em todas as colunas ele mostra os dados da pesquisa anterior.

Lembrando que o Datatable é inicializado junto com a página, mas os dados são recarregados a cada pesquisa pelo pesquisar.

Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Comment: Poderia colocar seu código Ajax na sua pergunta?

Comment: Acabei de colocar, como eu disse antes, uso o jquery template

Comment: Ola, já fez um console.log à variavel retorno, para ver se a informação que vem do ajax é a correta?
Não estou muito dentro da biblioteca DataTables mas experimente logo ao inicio usar o metodo clear() da biblioteca.

Comment: Cara, era isto mesmo, a clear

Comment: Ola, post por favor a solução e marque como certo. Assim fica respondido e pode ajudar outros que tenham a mesma questão.

Comment: Escreva na resposta, assim posso marcar como certo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvido, o problema é que a função "Datatable" deve ser incializado com letra maiúscula, em vez de minuscula, conforme o exemplo abaixo:

```
 tabela = $('#tabelaProdutos').DataTable({
                    "bBootstrap": true,
                    "bLengthChange": true,
                    "bFilter": true,
                    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
                    "bDestroy": true,
                    "oLanguage": {
                        "sProcessing": "Processando...",
                        "sLengthMenu": "Mostrar _MENU_ registros",
                        "sZeroRecords": "Não foram encontrados resultados",
                        "sInfo": "Mostrando de _START_ até _END_ de _TOTAL_ registros",
                        "sInfoEmpty": "Mostrando de 0 até 0 de 0 registros",
                        "sInfoFiltered": "(filtrado de _MAX_ registros no total)",
                        "sInfoPostFix": "",
                        "sSearch": "Pesquisar em todas as colunas:",
                        "sUrl": "",
                        "oPaginate": {
                            "sFirst": "Primeiro",
                            "sPrevious": "Anterior",
                            "sNext": "Seguinte",
                            "sLast": "Último"
                        }
                    },
                    "sDom": '<"H"lf>t<"F"iTp>',
                    "oTableTools": {
                        "aButtons": [],
                        "sRowSelect": "single"
                    }
                });
```